# Using for loop with an object name

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a simple for loop as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)
{

}
```

Now I have 20 labels (label1, label2, label3 and so on..)

I would like to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i > 20; i++)
{
    label[i].Text = String.Empty;
}
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: put the labels in an array, then use the code you posted?

Comment: The _best_ would be to use descriptive names instead of `Label123`.

Comment: label1 is not the same as label[1].

Comment: what is it? winforms? wpf? webforms?

Comment: @Moritz by the time all the labels are added to an array, you could just make individual assignments.

Comment: your loop is wrong. use `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)`

Comment: @cadrell0 the difference is that using an array separates the data from the operations performed on the data, which is good practice as far as I'm concerned. Say next time OP wants to perform N arbitrary operations on each label... instead of copy/pasting N lines of code for each label (N*20), he can just add N lines to the for loop (N*1).

Comment: Wouldn't a method `FooTheLabel(Label label)` achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your labels are placed on one container, say `Form`, you may do the following:

```
foreach(Label l in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    l.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Same for any other container, say, `Panel` or `GroupBox`, just replace `this` with the name of the container (`panel1.Controls`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Create an array or list of labels and loop through that list to set the properties of each label

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
labels.Add(label1);

foreach(Label l in labels)
{
    l.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd call your solution a design-flaw, but I'd go for something like this:

```
var itemArray = this.Controls.OfType<Label>();

foreach(var item in itemArray)
{
    item.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if its the easiest, it is the shortest though..

```
this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().ForEach(lbl => { lbl.Text = String.Empty; });
```

Comment: I gave your answer only an upvote for using `ForEach`...still getting accustomed to it myself

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use FindControl with something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   (FindControl("txt" + i.ToString())).Text = String.Emty;
}
```